# Errors in independent t-test in R

Tags: r, t-test

I'm just getting started with R and I need your help on performing an independent sample t-test. I have tried different codes but I keep getting errors. The dataset is a pretty big one, provided by my teacher, and it's essentially about how people perceive different types of humor. My task is to find what the difference between men (coded as 5) and women (coded as 4) is on the `imgagg1` variable. Here's what I tried:

```
Xdata<-Xdata[-c(1,2,311,312,313,614,619,808,815),] # I eliminated these rows because of this error that I keep getting even after removing the rows: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Women<-Xdata[which(Xdata$gender=="4"),"imgagg1"]

Men<-Xdata[which(Xdata$gender=="5"),"imgagg1"]

t.test(Xdata$Women,Xdata$Men)
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I also tried this, but get the same errors:

```
Xdata<-Xdata[-c(1,2,311,312,313,614,619,808,815),]
Women<-Xdata%>%
  filter(gender=="4")%>%
  pull(imgagg1)
Men<-Xdata%>%
  filter(gender=="5")%>%
  pull(imgagg1)
t.test(Women,Men)
```

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've been busting my head over this but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Your `Women` and `Men` objects aren't columns in their own right.  They're just R objects.  So try `t.test(Women, Men)`.  That might work.  But without a simple, repoducible example that includes test data it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: I've tried that, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  "It still doesn't work" isn't specific enough.  The syntax I gave you in my first comment is correct.  So that suggests an issue with your data.  (Perhaps `gender` is numeric or `imgagg1` is character?)  Without seeing (some of) your data, we/I cannot help you further.

Comment: Hi Elizabeth B. - try copying and pasting what the console prints when you run `dput(head(Xdata, 25))`, which will give folks the structure of the first 25 lines of your data and they can work from there to help you (I chose 25 that arbitrarily). You can also restrict to only relevant columns by `dput(head(Xdata[,c("gender","imgagg")], 25))`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @jpsmith! Here's the output I get: ```structure(list(gender = c(NA, "7", NA, "4", "4", "4", "5", "4", 
"4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", 
"4", "6", "4", "4"), imgagg1 = c(NA, NA, NA, "5", "5", "4", "3", 
"4", "1", "5", "4", "5", "6", "7", "4", "6", "3", "1", "5", "2", 
"5", "6", "5", "7", "2")), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are two things going on. If the structure of your data are correct, your numbers are actually considered characters by R. Also, there may be some confusion in your application of the `t.test`. You create two separate datasets, `Men` and `Women` - then you used `t.test(Xdata$Women,Xdata$Men)` - this is trying to find the variable `Men` or `Women` in the dataset `Xdata`, but those variables dont exist (`Men` and `Women` are their own datasets with one variable, `imgagg1`).

To run `t.test()` on your sample data, I did the following:

```
Xdata <- structure(list(gender = c(NA, "7", NA, "4", "4", "4", "5", "4",  "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5",  "4", "6", "4", "4"), imgagg1 = c(NA, NA, NA, "5", "5", "4", "3",  "4", "1", "5", "4", "5", "6", "7", "4", "6", "3", "1", "5", "2",  "5", "6", "5", "7", "2")), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Colums are currently character, Convert these two columns to numeric. Not the numbers here reflect the position in this simplified dataset. In the real dataset, you will want to identify them as `c(x,y)` assuming `gender` and `imgagg1` are in column number x and y, respectively.
Xdata[1:2] <- lapply(Xdata[1:2], as.numeric)

Women <- Xdata[which(Xdata$gender == 4),"imgagg1"]

Men <- Xdata[which(Xdata$gender == 5),"imgagg1"]

t.test(Women,Men)

# > t.test(Women,Men)
# 
# Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  Women and Men
# t = 0.21418, df = 12.083, p-value = 0.834
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#   -1.527540  1.860873
# sample estimates:
#   mean of x mean of y 
# 4.333333  4.166667
```

You also dont need to remove the missing data in the step `Xdata[-c(1,2,311,312,313,614,619,808,815),]` - the function `na.omit = TRUE` will
(as you can guess!) omit the `NA` values. Most functions for mathematical functions will allow you to omit `NA` values like this (i.e., `sum(x, na.omit = TRUE)`)

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, this is super helpful! One more question, though. Just to make things easier because this is a huge dataset, I did the following and I need to know if it's correct: `XdataQ3<-Xdata%>%
 select(gender,imgagg1)XdataQ3[1:2] <- lapply(XdataQ3[1:2], as.numeric)

Women <- XdataQ3[which(XdataQ3$gender == 4),"imgagg1"]

Men <- XdataQ3[which(XdataQ3$gender == 5),"imgagg1"]
t.test(Women,Men)`

Comment: This should work - sometimes you may get an error because more than one package uses a `select()` function (i.e. `MASS`) so to make sure you specify which package you are using `select()` in, you can write `XdataQ3 <- Xdata %>%  dplyr::select(gender, imgagg1)` or `XdataQ3 <- dplyr::select(Xdata, gender, imgagg1)`